# ASP.Net Core 1.0 Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information

Tags: entity-framework, iis-7.5, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to deploy ASP. Net Core 1.0 in IIS 7.5.7 with Entity Framework
When trying to access site, an error message is coming in the log file like below.

fail: Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[0]
      An unhandled exception has occurred: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
      System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.
         at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
         at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.get_DefinedTypes()
         at System.Linq.Enumerable.d__16`2.MoveNext()
         at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
         at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ApplicationModels.DefaultApplicationModelProvider.OnProvidersExecuting(ApplicationModelProviderContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActionDescriptorProvider.BuildModel()
         at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActionDescriptorProvider.GetDescriptors()
         at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActionDescriptorProvider.OnProvidersExecuting(ActionDescriptorProviderContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Infrastructure.DefaultActionDescriptorsCollectionProvider.GetCollection()
         at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Infrastructure.DefaultActionDescriptorsCollectionProvider.get_ActionDescriptors()
         at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Routing.AttributeRoute.GetInnerRoute()
         at Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Routing.AttributeRoute.RouteAsync(RouteContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNet.Routing.RouteCollection.d__9.MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
         at Microsoft.AspNet.Builder.RouterMiddleware.d__4.MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
         at Microsoft.AspNet.Session.SessionMiddleware.d__8.MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
         at Microsoft.AspNet.Session.SessionMiddleware.d__8.MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
         at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNet.ExceptionTrackingMiddleware.d__4.MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
         at Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler.IISPlatformHandlerMiddleware.d__8.MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
         at Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.d__6.MoveNext()

Page displaying like

The website cannot display the page 
 HTTP 500
   Most likely causes:
•The website is under maintenance.
•The website has a programming error.

I tried this link for deployement
http://www.strathweb.com/2015/12/running-asp-net-5-website-on-iis/

How can I find which dll cannot load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for my problem.

Goto Project.json, then check for all the references in the file.
If any reference found without "x.x.x-rc1-final" (x = any version number)
please remove that reference or add supported version with rc1-final

This will solve the problem.

Thank You